# Disable math concealement in nvim+vimtex

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin, neovim-plugin

I use nvim with vimex, and I try to undo the concealement of math formulae.

If I use the command  `:set conceallevel=0` in vim, it works and remove the concealement.

Nevertheless, I am unable to put this instruction in the configuration files.

For example, I tried to write `conceallevel=0` at the end of init.vim  file, but this does nothing:
it seems than vimex overwrites it.

I found on the web some related questions, but nothing specificaly with nvim and maybe it doesnt work for this reason.

Do you have an idea about it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Tried `:help vimtex-syntax-conceal`?